# Javascript Ajax not working in Chromium based browsers

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this piece of code to import a JSON file called x.level.json, where x can be any number for which I made a file, in the 'levels' directory at the source of the page and turn it into a string called 'jsonstring'. It works fine in Firefox, but when I try it in Opera, Chromium or Google Chrome nothing happens.

```
var l = 0; //for this example, normally 'l' is a function parameter
var xhr;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        else xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 

        xhr.open('GET', 'levels/'+l+'.level.json', false);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState===4 && xhr.status===200) {
                jsonstring = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
        xhr.send();
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Console or Network details in the browsers' developer tools? Are any errors reported? Is a request to `levels/0.level.json` listed as completing with a 200 OK status?

Comment: Javascript variable names must begin with a letter or $ or _. Your example using 1 would cause a problem.

Comment: @LeoFarmer That is just the weird font, it's actually an l.